# Show for almost all $x \in [1, \infty)$ the function $g_x (y) = \frac{xf(x^2y)\sin(x+y)}{y}$ is integrable in $[1,\infty)$ if $f \in L^1([1,\infty))$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Question: Show for almost all $x \in [1, \infty)$ the function $g_x (y) = \frac{xf(x^2y)\sin(x+y)}{y}$ is integrable in $[1,\infty)$ if $f \in L^1([1,\infty))$.

My attempt:
Given any $x \in [1, \infty)$, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_1^\infty g_x(y) \,dy &= \int_1^\infty \frac{xf(x^2y)\sin(x+y)}{y}\, dy\\
&\leq x \int_1^\infty |f(x^2y)|\, dy\\
&\leq \frac{1}{x} \Vert f \Vert_{L^1([1, \infty))}
\end{align*}
So, $\Vert g_x \Vert_{L^1([1, \infty))} < \infty$ whenever $x \in [1,\infty)$ so $g_x$ is integrable in $[1,\infty)$ for almost all $x \in [1,\infty)$.

May I check if there are any gaps in my proof? As I'm not sure why the answer only require the function to be integrable for almost all $x \in [1,\infty)$ instead of all of $[1,\infty)$. Any hints/solutions are appreciated.

Comment: The integrand should be in absolute value also in the two first integrals, and the $x$ in the final upperbound should be $\frac1x,$ but apart from this your proof seems fine and I don't understand either why they say "almost".

Comment: @AnneBauval could you explain what u mean by the final upperbound should be $1/x$ instead?

Comment: $\int_1^\infty |f(x^2y)|\, \color{red}{x^2}dy=\int_{x^2}^\infty |f(t)|\, dt.$

Comment: @AnneBauval I am using the bound of $|\sin(x+y)| \leq 1$ for any $x,y \in [1, \infty)$ and $|y| \geq 1$ for any $y \in [1, \infty)$. So, I am left with a single factor of $x$.

Comment: Indeed, and this $x$ must be multiplied by the $\color{red}{\frac1{x^2}}$ which you forgot during your substitution in the integral.

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you, have made the necessary edits.

Comment: @AnneBauval do go ahead!

Comment: I do not believe that is a proper use of the closing process. It is better to leave an answer as community wiki confirming the correctness for future users.

Comment: L-JS "go ahead"? I could do nothing more. But thanks to @Cameron's advice, I retracted my close vote. Please *accept* (upvoting is not really useful, I think) my (community wiki) answer, to close the question properly.

Answer (score 1):

1. The integrand should be in absolute value also in the two first integrals, and
2. the $x$
   in the final upper bound should be $\frac1x,$

but apart from this your proof seems fine and I don't understand either why they say "almost".

Edit: the second mistake has now been understood and corrected.